# How can I declare a matrix in Matlab where the column size is not fixed?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have MATLAB code that I need to convert to C using the MATLAB Coder. Here few lines of the code:

```
for k = 1 : K
    delay_points_local(k,:) = arg_max_tau(k) - 0.3  :  step_tau : arg_max_tau(k) + 0.3;
    CFO_points_local(k,:) = arg_max_CFO(k) - 0.005  :  step_CFO : arg_max_CFO(k) + 0.005;
    [g_prime_bar_all_relays_local(:,:,k)] = Importance_function_grid( y_rd , CFO_points_local(k,:) , delay_points_local(k,:));
end
```

I need to define the `delay_points_local` and `CFO_points local` where the row size is fixed but the column size is changing (depends on `arg_max_tau(k)`). Here is the code for `arg_max_tau(k)`:

```
for k = 1:K
    pdf_tau = step_CFO*sum(g_prime_bar_all_relays(:,:,k),1); 
    [~,tau_k_pos] = max(pdf_tau);
    arg_max_tau(k) = delay_points(1,tau_k_pos);

    pdf_CFO = step_tau*sum(g_prime_bar_all_relays(:,:,k),2);
    [~,CFO_k_pos] = max(pdf_CFO);
    arg_max_CFO(k) = CFO_points(1, CFO_k_pos);
end
```

How can I define the two variables `delay_points_local` and `CFO_points_local` so that I can convert it into C?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, you want to create a matrix where each row has a variable amount of columns. That is not possible in MATLAB.  You must create matrices where the number of columns is the same for every row.  You can only achieve this by using cell arrays perhaps.

Comment: Thank you. I have used the cell arrays, but the code generator shows the error that it does not support "cell arrays".

Comment: Ah I missed your MATLAB coder use.  In that case, you're going to have to rewrite your MATLAB code so that it simply doesn't store `delay_points_local` and `CFO_points_local` as matrices. You may have to just use temporary variables instead. If these variables are not important after that first `for` loop is finished, then simply do that instead.